# non-POD type in variable argumentlist

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, ipad

I'm using a soap library and switching the project to the Apple LLVM 3.0 Compiler gave me a few hundred errors, anyway almost fixed them all. Exept for one.

On the line 'while (eachObject .....' 
gives me a compiler error 'error: second argument to 'va_arg' is of non-POD type 'id' [-Wnon-pod-varargs,3]'

I don't know the type of the passed objects. It worked in previous versions of the compiler, but this one is a little bit picky.

```
- (id)initWithObjects:(id)firstObj, ...{
if(self = [self init]) {

    id eachObject;

    va_list argumentList;
    if (firstObj) {
        [self.items addObject: firstObj];
        va_start(argumentList, firstObj);

        while (eachObject == va_arg(argumentList, id)) {
            [self.items addObject: eachObject];
        }
        va_end(argumentList);
    }
}
return self;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `id`, try asking for the argument as a `void *` and casting that to `id` in a separate step. I'm not sure why clang is throwing a fit about this, but this should make it happy at least.

Comment: Make sure to mark this question as "answered" if everything's solved!

Comment: Here is a good reference: http://builderror.com/article/47/second-argument-to-va-arg-is-of-non-pod-type